# MVVM radiobuttons

Tags: data-binding, mvvm

Someone please help. I have an interesting issue. I am trying to implement an MVVM app and I want to bind to radiobuttons in my view.

Here's my view:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=NoteGeneral, Mode=TwoWay}">General</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=NoteContact, Mode=TwoWay}" >Contact</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=NoteAddress, Mode=TwoWay}" >Address</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=NotePhone, Mode=TwoWay}" >Phone</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Here's my ViewModel:

```
    bool _NoteGeneral;
    public bool NoteGeneral
    {
        get { return _NoteGeneral; }
        set
        {
            _NoteGeneral = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NoteGeneral");
        }
    }

    bool _NoteContact;
    public bool NoteContact
    {
        get { return _NoteContact; }
        set
        {
            _NoteContact = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NoteContact");
        }
    }

    bool _NoteAddress;
    public bool NoteAddress
    {
        get { return _NoteAddress; }
        set
        {
            _NoteAddress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NoteAddress");
        }
    }

    bool _NotePhone;
    public bool NotePhone
    {
        get { return _NotePhone; }
        set
        {
            _NotePhone = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NotePhone");
        }
    }
```

The problem is this, when I click the different radiobuttons the property setter only gets called the first time(when i run thru debugging). e.g. When I click NoteGeneral, NoteContact, then NoteGeneral again only the first two clicks update my viewmodel. I think I might have something wrong with my binding, or maybe I'm approaching this the completely wrong way.

Can anyone help?

How should I implement radiobutton selections in my viewmodel?

### .NET 4 and Later

This issue with RadioButton binding was resolved by Microsoft when .NET 4 was released.  Binding of RadioButtons now works as you would expect without any of the work-arounds listed below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mthalman/archive/2008/09/04/wpf-data-binding-with-radiobutton.aspx).

I haven't implemented the solution provided but it makes sense.  The underlying framework control breaks you bindings when a click is performed.  The solution is to override the method that does this and just rely on the bindings.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284752/mvvm-binding-radio-buttons-to-a-view-model for some other solutions, particularly a rather simple solution involving a list box.

Comment: The link is down that's why you shouldn't post links as answers.

Answer (score 16):

[Jaime Rodriguez](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/default.aspx), who works at Microsoft on WPF, publishes an unabridged Q&A on WPF, and the latest issue has a post on RadioButtons and MVVM !

The post is at http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2009/09/22/wpf-discussion-090922.aspx, and you want to look at the last item in that post. I tested the solution and it works to my satisfaction.

Quoted for convenience:

> I've worked around this issue in .NET 3.5 SP1.  Here's how I data bind a group of radio buttons to an enum-valued property:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="New folder"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=PublishTarget,
                    Converter={StaticResource equalityConverter},
                    ConverterParameter={x:Static local:PublishTarget.NewServerFolder}, Mode=TwoWay}"
        GroupName="1" />

    <RadioButton Content="Existing folder"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=PublishTarget,
                    Converter={StaticResource equalityConverter},
                    ConverterParameter={x:Static local:PublishTarget.ExistingServerFolder},
                    Mode=TwoWay}"
        GroupName="2" />

    <RadioButton Content="Local folder"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=PublishTarget,
                    Converter={StaticResource equalityConverter},
                    ConverterParameter={x:Static local:PublishTarget.LocalFolder},
                    Mode=TwoWay}"
        GroupName="3" />
</StackPanel>
```

> Setting each radio button's GroupName to a unique value prevents the bindings from getting clobbered when the user clicks on a radio button.  Here I'm relying on the data source to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, which will tell the other radio buttons to update.  A similar approach should work for radio buttons in an ItemsControl.

Answer (score 8):

I've written [a simple tip](http://www.ryeol.com/27) for this problem on my blog.

In this case, you should write the View and the ViewModel as the following:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsGeneralNote}">General</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsContactNote}">Contact</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsAddressNote}">Address</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsPhoneNote}">Phone</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

```
public enum Note
{
    General,
    Contact,
    Address,
    Phone,
}

...

    Note note = Note.General;

    public Note Note
    {
        get { return this.note; }
        set
        {
            if (this.note == value)
                return;

            this.note = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Note");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsGeneralNote");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsContactNote");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsAddressNote");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsPhoneNote");
        }
    }

    public bool IsGeneralNote
    {
        get { return Note == Note.General; }
        set { Note = value ? Note.General : Note; }
    }

    public bool IsContactNote
    {
        get { return Note == Note.Contact; }
        set { Note = value ? Note.Contact : Note; }
    }

    public bool IsAddressNote
    {
        get { return Note == Note.Address; }
        set { Note = value ? Note.Address : Note; }
    }

    public bool IsPhoneNote
    {
        get { return Note == Note.Phone; }
        set { Note = value ? Note.Phone : Note; }
    }
...
```

Comment: This solution doesn't address the problem of RadioButton bindings getting clobbered when the button is selected, does it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` at XAML binding like:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <RadioButton Name="rdbTimeFormat12" GroupName="TimeFormat" Content="12 Hrs" IsChecked="{Binding Radio1IsCheck,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <RadioButton Name="rdbTimeFormat24" GroupName="TimeFormat" Margin="40,0,0,0" Content="24 Hrs" IsChecked="{Binding Radio2IsCheck,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Just as a note, the code still needs this suggested fix, despite the question saying that the issue is fixed. I am using .NET 6 and the binding didn't work until I implemented Vijay's fix.