# Odd behavior when trying to change a bound RadioButton in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radio-button, ivalueconverter

I've bound two radio buttons in my `Child` window to an `Enum` in my `ViewModel` which is constructed in the Main window. The binding works as expected but I have noticed a very odd behavior which I can't solve. I have provided all the code here so you can reconstruct the problem easily for yourself.

Here are the steps to see this odd behavior:

1. Click on the button in the MainWindow
2. The ChildWindow opens and the RadioButton is set to User
3. Choose Automatic and then Choose User again
4. Close the ChildWindow and reopen it again! Try to change the `RadioButton` to Automatic. It won't change!

```
    <Window x:Class="RadioButtonBinding.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

        <Button Content="Display Child Window" Click="DisplayChildWindow"/> 
    </Window>
```

```
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var viewModel = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        private void DisplayChildWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var win = new ChildWindow {DataContext = (ViewModel) DataContext};
            win.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

```
    <Window x:Class="RadioButtonBinding.ChildWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:radioButtonBinding="clr-namespace:RadioButtonBinding"
            Title="ChildWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
        <Window.Resources>
            <radioButtonBinding:EnumBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumBooleanConverter"/>
        </Window.Resources>

        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton Content="Automatic" 
                         GroupName="CalcMode"
                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=CalcMode, 
                                             Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, 
                                             ConverterParameter={x:Static radioButtonBinding:CalcMode.Automatic}}"/>

            <RadioButton Content="Custom"
                         GroupName="CalcMode"
                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=CalcMode, 
                                             Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, 
                                             ConverterParameter={x:Static radioButtonBinding:CalcMode.User}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

```
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        private CalcMode calcMode = CalcMode.User;
        public CalcMode CalcMode
        {
            get { return calcMode; }
            set
            {
                calcMode = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CalcMode");
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler == null) return;

            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

```
    public class EnumBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var paramEnum = parameter as Enum;
            var valueEnum = value as Enum;

            return Equals(paramEnum, valueEnum);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var parameterEnum = parameter as Enum;
            if (parameterEnum == null)
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            return parameterEnum;
        }
    }

    public enum CalcMode : byte
    {
        Automatic,

        User,
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I suspect it must be the `Converter` but I don't know why? It just falls into a loop.

Comment: Any particular reason your `enum` inherits `byte`?

Comment: @Jammer No, why? but it doesn't work even if I don't inherit.

Comment: Have a read of this http://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/

Comment: @Jammer Thanks for the article. For the current project I need to stick with the method mentioned in the question. Any ideas why it is not working? The converter part seems to fall into a loop!

Comment: A radio button value `checked` is bool not Enum ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jammer That's why I'm using the `Converter`.

Comment: @Vahid, I copied full example, but cannot reproduce the issue. But still, try check `value` in ConvertBack method: `var parameterEnum = parameter as Enum; bool? ischecked = value as bool?; if (parameterEnum != null && ischecked == true) return parameterEnum; return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;`

Comment: @ASh Thank you so much ASh, I updated the steps in my question. As expected it was because of the Converter. Your solution seems to work. Please post it as an answer so I can choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
What about converting the enum to bool as follows?

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (parameter == null || !(bool)value)
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    var parameterEnum = parameter as Enum;

    return parameterEnum;
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't work. In my `ViewModel` I have defined the value as an `Enum` so I have to ConvertBack to en Enum.