# Horizontal RadioButtons in ListBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In WPF I am trying to binding radio buttons to a property in the ViewModel such as this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2285732

Everything works fine, except that the Buttons are stacked Vertically. Now, this seems an easy fix, just modify the ItemsPanelTemplate.

Here's my code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemOptions}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption}">
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
               <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"  >
                            <RadioButton Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                 IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
           </Style>
     </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

However, the items remain stacked vertically. Any ideas why this has no effect on the orientation of the ListBox?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your XAML and F5 and it works fine. Items are stacked horizontally. Which .Net version are you using?

Comment: Then I don't understand... I am also using 4.0, and the same exact XAML works fine in my PC....

Comment: HighCore - well, I appreciate the quick help regardless. The answer below did work for me - so, I'm not sure where we differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ListBox.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
          <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer" 
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanContentScroll="False">
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
          </ScrollViewer>
      </ControlTemplate>
 </ListBox.Template>
```

I tried to get this working with the ItemsPanelTemplate, as you did, without success. This worked great for me. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example without styling. Note that the `WrapPanel` handles the layout.

```
    <ListBox Margin="0,10,0,0"        
             ItemsSource="{StaticResource Orders}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding CustomerName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Data with the model defined in code behind.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <model:Orders x:Key="Orders">
        <model:Order CustomerName="Alpha"
                    OrderId="997"
                    InProgress="True" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Beta"
                    OrderId="998"
                    InProgress="False" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Omega"
                    OrderId="999"
                    InProgress="True" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Zeta"
                    OrderId="1000"
                    InProgress="False" />
    </model:Orders>
</Page.Resources>
```

Result

[image]