# WPF Listbox content showing Radio buttons list. Check default radio button from the list initially

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I was using this link to solve my problem.
[MVVM: Binding radio buttons to a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284752/mvvm-binding-radio-buttons-to-a-view-model)

Now my current issue is , i would like to show some radio button from the listbox as checked by default when the screen is loaded at first.

Kind regards,
Suresh

Comment: set that corresponding `ListBoxItem`'s VM value as selected in your VM on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your RadioButtons are bound to your ViewModel, then all you need to do is set the value in your ViewModel to the default that you desire in the ViewModel's constructor. This is what makes using a ViewModel so convenient, you can manipulate the data and its values without concerning the user interface.