# Binding RadioButton.IsChecked with Listbox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My View is clickable like a radiobutton with about 7 other of these radiobuttons, but my listbox is not updating it's selected property unless I click outside of my radiobutton.

Basically I have a AbstractTask as my base. I have 7 child classes. I want to be able to select one of these AbstractTasks. That's all i'm after. So in my main window i have this.

```
<Window x:Class="AdvancedTaskAssigner.View.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:AdvancedTaskAssigner.View"
        Title="MainWindowView" Height="300" Width="300" SizeToContent="Height">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=listTasks, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />

        <ListBox x:Name="listTasks" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding IsSelected}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <v:AbstractTaskView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

since this is a library and not a application I had to put this in the Constructor of MainWindowView

**MainWindowView.xaml.cs**

```
    public MainWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var atvm = new ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel();
        atvm.LoadTasks();
        this.DataContext = atvm;
    }
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    internal void LoadTasks()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AbstractTask)).GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractTask)));
        Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AbstractTask)), typeof(AbstractTask));
        foreach (Type t in typelist)
        {
            if(!t.IsAbstract && t.BaseType.Equals(typeof(AbstractTask)))
            {
                tasks.Add(new AbstractTaskViewModel(t));
            }

        }
    }
    private Type[] GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly assembly, Type baseClass)
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(baseClass)).ToArray();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<AbstractTaskViewModel> tasks = new ObservableCollection<AbstractTaskViewModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<AbstractTaskViewModel> Tasks
    {
        get { return tasks; }
    }

}
```

**AbstractTaskViewModel.cs**

```
public class AbstractTaskViewModel
{
    public AbstractTaskViewModel(Type task)
    {
        if (!task.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractTask)))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} is not a subclass of AbstractTask", task.Name));
        }
        Task = task;
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return GetCustomAttribute(0);
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return GetCustomAttribute(1);
        }
    }
    public bool IsSelected{get;set;}

    private string GetCustomAttribute(int index)
    {
        var descriptions = (DescriptionAttribute[])Task.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (descriptions.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return descriptions[index].Description;
    }

    protected readonly Type Task;
}
```

**AbstractTaskView.xaml**

```
<RadioButton 
    x:Class="AdvancedTaskAssigner.View.AbstractTaskView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" GroupName="AbstractTasks" Background="Transparent" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <RadioButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="MyHead" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Background="LightGray" Margin="20,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Panel.ZIndex="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,2" MinWidth="50" />
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="Myoooo" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,10,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5,15,5,2" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyHead" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                </Trigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </RadioButton.Template>

</RadioButton>
```

this is what i am getting..

I want the green border to be the selected item. not what the Listbox's Selected item is. The bottom text box is the name of the selected item.
[image: What the outcome of that code is]

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues related to binding IsChecked property of RadioButton. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284752/mvvm-binding-radio-buttons-to-a-view-model) or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2008/09/04/wpf-data-binding-with-radiobutton.aspx). You can apply the solution presented in the first link using your AbstractTaskView instead of RadioButton. Replace your listbox in MainWindowView with the code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listTasks" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <v:AbstractTaskView Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                             IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

You have to also remove the folowing part of code from *AbstractTaskView*:

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

I hope you don't need *IsSelected* property of *AbstractTaskViewModel* to be set. But if you do, you can set it for example in *Checked* event handler in *AbstractTaskView* code behind (I know it's not pretty solution).

Answer (score -1):

I see you're binding the IsSelected  (boolean) to the SelectedItem  (object)

Comment: that is the most current attempt to make it work, I've tried a few other things as well.