# MVVM Keeping track of selected Radio Button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, radio-button

I have an observable collection which gives values to radio buttons. As the user moves from one item to another, I would like the corresponding group radio button to be automatically selected if the user previously selected it.

To summarize it's a multiple question type exam and i want to keep the radio button selected as the user navigates from one question to another.

Here's the view:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Choices}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Content="{Binding .}" 
                                 Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveAnswerCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                 GroupName="choices"
                                 />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The observable collection:

```
public static ObservableCollection<ExamModel> Questions
    {
        get
        {
            return _questions;
        }
        set
        {
            _questions = value;
        }
    }

//this is how i keep track of which item is currently active
public ExamModel CurrentQuestion
    {
        get { return _currentQuestion; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentQuestion != value)
            {
                _currentQuestion = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentQuestion");
            }
        }

    }
```

The Model:

```
public List<string> Choices
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_choices == null)
                _choices = new List<string>();

            return _choices; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (_choices != value)
            {
                _choices = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Choices");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using this approach [MVVM: Binding radio buttons to a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284752/mvvm-binding-radio-buttons-to-a-view-model) and binding the **SelectedItem** property with the value of the selected radio button.

The selected radio button is kept track on one of the fields of my observable collection **CurrentQuestion.StudentAnswer**.

Answer (score 0):

There is interesting article how to deal with RadioButton binding in many ways.

See [Jerry Nixon on Windows: Let’s code! Data binding to a Radio Button in XAML](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/12/lets-code-data-binding-to-radio-button.html)