# How to get selected radio button in selected list item from wpf listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, wpf-controls

Image of the list box is as follows:

[Listbox with Dynamic column with check boxes and static radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4acg5.png)

I have to look for the selected items from list box and selected radio button for each selected item

```
<ListBox Height="226" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="404,339,0,0" Name="listBoxItems" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282" SelectionChanged="listBoxItems_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,5,0,0">
                        <CheckBox Width="130" x:Name="chbPrescr"  Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}">
                            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Width="115"></TextBlock>-->

                        </CheckBox>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdOD" Width="40" Content ="OD" Checked="rdOD_Checked" />
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdBD" Width="40" Content ="BD" Checked="rdBD_Checked"/>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rdTDS" Width="40" Content ="TDS" Checked="rdTDS_Checked"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And at the postback event I am getting selected list item but not the selected radio button for that selected list item

```
foreach (var items in listBoxItems.SelectedItems)
{ 
    string a = items.ToString();
    ItemCollection itemCollection = listBoxItems.Items;
    object currentItem = itemCollection.CurrentItem;
}
```

I need to know how can I get the category for each of the selected medicine. Thanks

Comment: You already using some binding. Why not binding the radiobuttons as well? Then you have the values in your viewmodels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind the `IsChecked` property of the `RadioButtons` to a source property of your data class:

[WPF + MVVM + RadioButton : Handle binding with single property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790017/wpf-mvvm-radiobutton-handle-binding-with-single-property)

This is the preferable solution.

The fastest one is probably to find the selected `RadioButton` in the visual tree:

```
private void listBoxItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var items in listBoxItems.SelectedItems)
    {
        ListBoxItem lbi = listBoxItems.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(items) as ListBoxItem;
        if (lbi != null)
        {
            RadioButton rb = FindVisualChildren<RadioButton>(lbi).FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsChecked == true);
            if (rb != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("selected: " + rb.Content.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        int NbChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj);

        for (int i = 0; i < NbChild; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childNiv2 in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childNiv2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```