# Vertical alignment of ContentControl in styled ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, vertical-alignment

I am using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2291655/31326) to style a `ListBox` as `RadioButton` in order to simplify my MVVM code by driving the selection of the checked radio button via an enum - rather than having a bunch of bools that I have to manually map  back and forth to the enum.

This works really well when the `ListBoxItem` content is a simple line of text. The radio button aligns with the text and all is happy.  But when I change the content to be a `UserControl`, the radio button for that choice gets rendered at the vertical mid-point of the `UserControl` rather than at the top (where I want it).

Here is some code and an image that better explains what I am trying to do (Note that a bunch of stuff has been left out for clarity):

The `UserControl` that I am inserting as content into one of the choices

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestCtl">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Label Margin="-5,0,0,0" Content="Choice #2"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,5">Option 1</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,5">Option 2</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,0">Option 3</CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The `ListBox` (with the aforementioned style defined elsewhere)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" 
             Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}" 
             SelectedValue="{Binding Blah Blah"}>
        <ListBoxItem Tag="Choice1" Content="Choice #1" />
        <ListBoxItem Tag="Choice2">
            <ContentControl>
                <subf:TestCtl />
            </ContentControl>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Tag="Choice3" Content="Choice #3"/>
        <ListBoxItem Tag="Choice4" Content="Choice #4" /> 
    </ListBox>
    <ComboBox blah blah/>
</StackPanel>
```

What it looks like when rendered:

[image]

I have tried setting both the `VerticalAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` as well as playing with `Margin` and `Padding`  in every location I can think of in both my xaml code and the style that I linked to, but no matter what I set I can't get the radio button and user control to align at their tops.

Is there anyway to achieve what I want by modifying either the style I am using or my code?  Or am I just flat out doing this wrong?

Comment: Style a ListBox as a RadioButton? You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790017/wpf-mvvm-radiobutton-handle-binding-with-single-property

Comment: @mm8 Funnily enough I actually saw that one for the first time today and previously I had googled MVVM Radio buttons multiple times.  I may try that approach but I'm wondering if I will still encounter the same alignment issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the RabioButtonList style change this:

```
 <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
                                    <!-- CHANGE THIS -->
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <RadioButton 
                                        Focusable="False"
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                        IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}"/>
                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                     <!------------------>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

In the user control set the label Padding to 5,0,0,0 (Thanks to mm8)

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
    <Label Margin="-5,0,0,0" Content="Choice #2" Padding="5,0,0,0"/>
    <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,5">Option 1</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,5">Option 2</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,0">Option 3</CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is very close, but it has aligned the tops of the radio buttons with the top of the textual labels.  Rather than the middle of the textual labels.  I'm guessing a negative margin on the `ContentPresenter` will fix this

Comment: Yes, I'm close to fix this

Comment: Well, the label "Choise #2" is inside the usercontrol, that's why you can't align to it, so at some point you'll have to put fixed margins, paddings etc or move the label out of the user control and put it in the style

Comment: I believe that for the current solution Choice #2 has to be in the user control as you can only set the content once.  But long term I think that multiline radio button may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Padding` of the `Label` to `0`:

```
<ListBoxItem Tag="Choice1" Content="Choice #1" />
<ListBoxItem Tag="Choice2">
    <UserControl>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <Label Content="Choice #2" Padding="0"/>
            <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,5">Option 1</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,5">Option 2</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox Margin="10,0,0,0">Option 3</CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
</ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem Tag="Choice3" Content="Choice #3"/>
<ListBoxItem Tag="Choice4" Content="Choice #4" />
```

This should fix the vertical alignment issue. But you shouldn't have to use a `ListBox` in the first place to be able to bind a `RadioButton` to a single source property:

[WPF + MVVM + RadioButton : Handle binding with single property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790017/wpf-mvvm-radiobutton-handle-binding-with-single-property)

Comment: That didn't actually do anything in my implementation.

Comment: When making the `Padding=0` change to my `UserControl` it does not change anything.

Comment: UserControl? You should set the Padding of the Label in the UserControl.

Comment: Thats what I meant.  In the Label in my UserControl

Comment: Then your issue is not reproducible based on the info you have provided. Post a *full* sample that can be just copy and pasted into a new window and run as-is.