# Why radio button on a WPF page changes state when I navigate to another page and come back?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a menu made of three radio buttons, each button for each page. Then I have 3 additional radio buttons on one of the pages.

The problem is when I checked one of the radio buttons on the page, and navigate to another page, and come back, then it is automatically unchecked.

Please help me with this
buttons in the inside a page are here

```
                <RadioButton Content="ICE" Grid.Column="1" 
                 Tag="/TabMenu;component/images/ice.jpg" 
                 CommandParameter="ICE"
                 Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                 IsChecked="{Binding myVar, Mode=OneWay}"        
                 Style="{StaticResource SelectionMenuStyle}"
                 GroupName="B"
                 />
            <RadioButton Content="MSP" Grid.Column="3"
                 Tag="/TabMenu;component/images/msp.jpg" 
                 CommandParameter="MSP"
                 Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                 IsChecked="{Binding myVar, Mode=OneWay}"       
                 Style="{StaticResource SelectionMenuStyle}" 
                         GroupName="B"
                 />
            <RadioButton Content="BEV" Grid.Column="5"
                 Tag="/TabMenu;component/images/bev.jpg" 
                 CommandParameter="BEV"
                 Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                 IsChecked="{Binding myVar, Mode=OneWay}"
                 Style="{StaticResource SelectionMenuStyle}"
                         GroupName="B"
                 />
```

and Menu buttons are here

```
       <RadioButton Content="Format wechseln" 
                            CommandParameter="ChangeFormat"
                            Command="{Binding MenuCommand}"
                            Style="{StaticResource 
                            MenuButtonStyle}"
                            GroupName="A"
                            />
        <RadioButton x:Name="MontageButton" Content="Montage" 
                            CommandParameter="Montage"
                            Command="{Binding MenuCommand}"
                            Style="{StaticResource 
                            MenuButtonStyle}"
                            IsChecked="True"
                            GroupName="A"
                            />
        <RadioButton Content="Einrichten" 
                            CommandParameter="Einrichten"
                            Command="{Binding MenuCommand}"
                            Style="{StaticResource 
                            MenuButtonStyle}"
                            GroupName="A"
                            />
```

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Radio button in WPF has a property GroupName each group of radio button must have separate GroupName for example if you have two group of radio button with three radio button in each group, name one's GroupName as group1 and other group as group2

Comment: The form has a constructor and a load method.  You may be running the load method.  I normally create a separate browser when navigating to another page so when I return the first page is still in same state that I left it.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz I already have different group names for each set of radio buttons

Comment: then you need to share code!

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz I added the code now please check and let know if you can help

Comment: you can not bind radio button like that, you need to use a converter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790017/wpf-mvvm-radiobutton-handle-binding-with-single-property check this post

Comment: i think you have very limited concept of MVVM

Comment: google for how to bind radio button in wpf using MVVM pattern

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz Yes i am new and learning it, Thanks by the way i try this

Comment: And also learn about WPF converters, And i made this WPF menu you can use if you like https://github.com/mwaqasaziz/WpfHamburgerStyleMenuBar_UsingWPFMenu

Comment: I checked it and my problem is not solved. I just want to know if i checked radio button and then navigate page then come back it automatically unchecked

Comment: are you from pakistan?